# Angular Web API PUT Model Not Recognised

Tags: angularjs, json, asp.net-web-api2

I'm having trouble PUTting a reasonably complex data model to a Web API controller using Angular.

Here's what we have so far:

Angular Controller:

```
$scope.saveDelivery = function () {
    var val = $('#run-value', $element)[0].value;
    console.info("Batsman: " + $scope.striker.Name + ", Shot: " + $scope.shot + " for " + val + " runs. ");

    if ($scope.game.Overs[$scope.over - 1].Deliveries == null) {
        $scope.game.Overs[$scope.over - 1].Deliveries = [];
    }

    console.info("Over: " + $scope.over + ", Delivery: " + $scope.delivery);
    if ($scope.delivery > 6) {
        $scope.over++;
        $scope.delivery = 1;
    }
    else {
        $scope.delivery++;
    }

    if ($scope.striker == undefined) {
        alert("No batsman selected");
    }
    else {

        var shot = {};

        shot.Id = 0;
        shot.Runs = $scope.runs;
        shot.Stroke = $scope.shot;
        if ($scope.runs == -5) {
            shot.Dismissal = $scope.shot;
        }
        else {
            shot.Dismissal = null;
        }

        var delivery = {};
        delivery.Id = 0;
        delivery.Number = $scope.delivery;
        delivery.Batter = $scope.striker;
        delivery.Bowler = $scope.nonstriker;
        delivery.Shot = shot;


        $scope.game.Overs[$scope.over - 1].Deliveries.push(delivery);
        console.info($scope.game);

        $http.put('/api/games/:id', { id: $scope.game.Id, game: $scope.game }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.info(data);
        });
        //$http.post('/score/testing', { Test: "This is a test" }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        //    console.info(data);
        //});
    }
}
```

API Controller:

```
// PUT: api/Games/5
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public IActionResult PutGame(int id, [FromBody] Game game)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return HttpBadRequest(ModelState);
    }
    ... etc...
```

The raw JSON data I'm grabbing in Fiddler looks like this (sorry for the formatting):

```
{"id":1,"game":{"Id":1,"Date":"2016-04-20T20:30:00","Team":{"Id":"a5abca2a-0e05-11e6-8596-4f0c9eb370be","Name":"Yellow Duckies","Players":null},"Opposition":"Miller Studios","Overs":[{"Id":1,"Number":1,"Innings":0,"Deliveries":[{"Id":0,"Number":2,"Batter":{"Id":"1a903e4a-0f8a-11e6-99ad-b3c19db370be","Email":"phil@email.address.here","Name":"Phil"},"Bowler":{},"Shot":{"Id":0,"Runs":2,"Stroke":2,"Dismissal":null}}]},{"Id":2,"Number":2,"Innings":0,"Deliveries":null},{"Id":3,"Number":3,"Innings":0,"Deliveries":null},{"Id":4,"Number":4,"Innings":0,"Deliveries":null},...
```

If I change the Web API PUT parameter to plain `object`, it will pick up the body just fine, so I'm guessing there's a problem with how the object is being parsed, however I'm damned if I can see where that problem sits. Here's the C# model:

```
namespace IndoorCricket.Models
{
    public enum Innings { Batting, Bowling }

    public class Game
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public virtual Team Team { get; set; }
        public string Opposition { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Over> Overs { get; set; }
    }


    public class Over
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Number { get; set; }
        public Innings Innings { get; set; }

        //public virtual Game Game { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Delivery> Deliveries { get; set; }
    }

    public class Delivery
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Number { get; set; }
        public virtual Shot Shot { get; set; }

        public virtual Player Bowler { get; set; }
        public virtual Player Batter { get; set; }
    }

    public class Shot
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Runs { get; set; }
        public Stroke Stroke { get; set; }
        public Dismissal Dismissal { get; set; }
    }

    public enum Stroke
    {
        Out     = -5,
        Dotball = 0,
        Single  = 1,
        Two     = 2,
        Three   = 3,
        Four    = 4,
        Five    = 5,
        Seven   = 7
    }

    [Flags]
    public enum Dismissal
    {
        Caught  = 1,
        Bowled  = 2,
        Runout  = 4,
        Stumped = 8,
        Mankad  = 16,
        LBW     = 32
    }
}
```

Anyone have better eyes that can spot the problem?

Comment: ...and apologies in advance for the pretty rough code. There's a lot of debugging / testing stuff in there that'll need cleaned up later.

Comment: Can you quicky try something ?  $http.put('/api/games/' + $scope.game.Id, { game: $scope.game }).suc...

Comment: @EduardUta ID is still picked up as normal but the Game parameter is still populated with null values. Effectively, that parameter is the same as a newly-initialised object. Zeroes for all int values and null for the child collection.

Comment: hmm, I think that $scope's antenna doesn't reach the place you are using it for the game object. Before the call, create a new game object (from $scope.game) and use the new object in the call.. { game: newGameObj })).

Comment: The controller expects a game, not something that contains a game, doesn't it?

Comment: @zeroflagL I see what you're saying, I think. It's quite a few more arguments to pass through in the request, but I'll give it a look and see what the result is.

Comment: Rather than fill the comments on this question up with Q&A, I'd appreciate any suggestions in this chat room: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7/c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was eventually resolved by changing the API parameter type from strongly-typed "Game" object to a vanilla `object`. From there, I used JSON.Net to deserialise the object and inspect what was being sent through.

Because I had a reasonable degree of depth in my nested JSON objects, I could see that a property that expected a value was getting null passed to it instead.

I've left it like this for the time being (although it feels icky and I will want to work this through further):

```
    public IActionResult PutGame(int id, [FromBody] object game)
    {
        JObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(game.ToString());
        Game g = obj.Root.First.Value<JToken>().First.ToObject<Game>();
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The `game` class it is trying to build from the body is not the root object. .NET will detect that `id` column and won't be able to map to the class `Game`. Are you able to make `game` in the JSON the root? Since it seems you are passing the "id" into the controller end point at the API anyway?

Also, where are your `Team` and `Player` classes specified?

Comment: I tried changing the method to a decoration of `[HttpPut]` and the actual method to simply take a Game object: `public IActionResult PutGame([FromBody] Game game)` but this makes no difference. I would have expected .Net to recognise the ID in the route and a separate argument being passed in the body anyway.